# Как в Unity сделать ломаную линию гладкой?

Tags: unity3d

Есть 2d игра. Рисую линию методом TrailRenderer за движущимся объектом(за шариком). TrailRenderer рисует ломаную линию. Как сделать ее гладкой. quality -> anti aliasing 8x не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал `LineRenderer` вместо `TrailRenderer`, координаты объекта передавал в скрипте в методе `FixedUpdate`, или в корутине. Помогло. Получилась довольно гладкая кривая.

Answer (score 1):

TrailRender создает мэш состоящий из прямоугольников(по два треугольника на каждый). Если вам нужно сделать гладкую кривую вам придется вручную разбивать ваши отрезки на сегменты и строить сглаженную кривую по методу безье.

У меня была подобная задача в одном из проектов, использовал чужой скрипт (возможно дописывал, уже не помню). Попробуйте через него рассчитывать сегменты для вашей кривой.

```
/**

This class demonstrates the code discussed in these two articles:

http://devmag.org.za/2011/04/05/bzier-curves-a-tutorial/
http://devmag.org.za/2011/06/23/bzier-path-algorithms/

Use this code as you wish, at your own risk. If it blows up 
your computer, makes a plane crash, or otherwise cause damage,
injury, or death, it is not my fault.

@author Herman Tulleken, dev.mag.org.za

*/


using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

/**
Class for representing a Bezier path, and methods for getting suitable   points to 
draw the curve with line segments.
*/
public class BezierPath
{
private const int SEGMENTS_PER_CURVE = 10;
private const float MINIMUM_SQR_DISTANCE = 0.01f;

// This corresponds to about 172 degrees, 8 degrees from a traight line
private const float DIVISION_THRESHOLD = -0.99f; 

private List<Vector3> controlPoints;

private int curveCount; //how many bezier curves in this path?

/**
    Constructs a new empty Bezier curve. Use one of these methods
    to add points: SetControlPoints, Interpolate, SamplePoints.
*/
public BezierPath()
{
    controlPoints = new List<Vector3>();
}

/**
    Sets the control points of this Bezier path.
    Points 0-3 forms the first Bezier curve, points 
    3-6 forms the second curve, etc.
*/
public void SetControlPoints(List<Vector3> newControlPoints)
{
    controlPoints.Clear();
    controlPoints.AddRange(newControlPoints);
    curveCount = (controlPoints.Count - 1) / 3;
}

/**
    Returns the control points for this Bezier curve.
*/
public List<Vector3> GetControlPoints()
{
    return controlPoints;
}

/**
    Calculates a Bezier interpolated path for the given points.
*/
public void Interpolate(List<Vector3> segmentPoints, float scale)
{
    controlPoints.Clear();

    if (segmentPoints.Count < 2)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < segmentPoints.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0) // is first
        {
            Vector3 p1 = segmentPoints[i];
            Vector3 p2 = segmentPoints[i + 1];                

            Vector3 tangent = (p2 - p1);
            Vector3 q1 = p1 + scale * tangent;

            controlPoints.Add(p1);
            controlPoints.Add(q1);
        }
        else if (i == segmentPoints.Count - 1) //last
        {
            Vector3 p0 = segmentPoints[i - 1];
            Vector3 p1 = segmentPoints[i];
            Vector3 tangent = (p1 - p0);
            Vector3 q0 = p1 - scale * tangent;

            controlPoints.Add(q0);
            controlPoints.Add(p1);
        }
        else
        {
            Vector3 p0 = segmentPoints[i - 1];
            Vector3 p1 = segmentPoints[i];
            Vector3 p2 = segmentPoints[i + 1];
            Vector3 tangent = (p2 - p0).normalized;
            Vector3 q0 = p1 - scale * tangent * (p1 - p0).magnitude;
            Vector3 q1 = p1 + scale * tangent * (p2 - p1).magnitude;

            controlPoints.Add(q0);
            controlPoints.Add(p1);
            controlPoints.Add(q1);
        }
    }

    curveCount = (controlPoints.Count - 1) / 3;
}   

/**
    Sample the given points as a Bezier path.
*/
public void SamplePoints(List<Vector3> sourcePoints, float minSqrDistance, float maxSqrDistance, float scale)
{
    if(sourcePoints.Count < 2)
    {
        return;
    }

    Stack<Vector3> samplePoints = new Stack<Vector3>();

    samplePoints.Push(sourcePoints[0]);

    Vector3 potentialSamplePoint = sourcePoints[1];

    int i = 2;

    for (i = 2; i < sourcePoints.Count; i++ )
    {
        if(
            ((potentialSamplePoint - sourcePoints[i]).sqrMagnitude > minSqrDistance) &&
            ((samplePoints.Peek() - sourcePoints[i]).sqrMagnitude > maxSqrDistance))
        {
            samplePoints.Push(potentialSamplePoint);
        }

        potentialSamplePoint = sourcePoints[i];
    }

    //now handle last bit of curve
    Vector3 p1 = samplePoints.Pop(); //last sample point
    Vector3 p0 = samplePoints.Peek(); //second last sample point
    Vector3 tangent = (p0 - potentialSamplePoint).normalized;
    float d2 = (potentialSamplePoint - p1).magnitude;
    float d1 = (p1 - p0).magnitude;
    p1 = p1 + tangent * ((d1 - d2)/2);

    samplePoints.Push(p1);
    samplePoints.Push(potentialSamplePoint);


    Interpolate(new List<Vector3>(samplePoints), scale);
}

/**
    Caluclates a point on the path.

    @param curveIndex The index of the curve that the point is on. For example, 
    the second curve (index 1) is the curve with controlpoints 3, 4, 5, and 6.

    @param t The paramater indicating where on the curve the point is. 0 corresponds 
    to the "left" point, 1 corresponds to the "right" end point.
*/
public Vector3 CalculateBezierPoint(int curveIndex, float t)
{
    int nodeIndex = curveIndex * 3;

    Vector3 p0 = controlPoints[nodeIndex];
    Vector3 p1 = controlPoints[nodeIndex + 1];
    Vector3 p2 = controlPoints[nodeIndex + 2];
    Vector3 p3 = controlPoints[nodeIndex + 3];

    return CalculateBezierPoint(t, p0, p1, p2, p3);
}

/**
    Gets the drawing points. This implementation simply calculates a certain number
    of points per curve.
*/
public List<Vector3> GetDrawingPoints0()
{
    List<Vector3> drawingPoints = new List<Vector3>();

    for (int curveIndex = 0; curveIndex < curveCount; curveIndex++)
    {
        if (curveIndex == 0) //Only do this for the first end point. 
        //When i != 0, this coincides with the 
        //end point of the previous segment,
        {
            drawingPoints.Add(CalculateBezierPoint(curveIndex, 0));
        }

        for (int j = 1; j <= SEGMENTS_PER_CURVE; j++)
        {
            float t = j / (float)SEGMENTS_PER_CURVE;
            drawingPoints.Add(CalculateBezierPoint(curveIndex, t));
        }
    }

    return drawingPoints;
}

/**
    Gets the drawing points. This implementation simply calculates a certain number
    of points per curve.

    This is a lsightly different inplementation from the one above.
*/
public List<Vector3> GetDrawingPoints1()
{
    List<Vector3> drawingPoints = new List<Vector3>();

    for (int i = 0; i < controlPoints.Count - 3; i += 3)
    {
        Vector3 p0 = controlPoints[i];
        Vector3 p1 = controlPoints[i + 1];
        Vector3 p2 = controlPoints[i + 2];
        Vector3 p3 = controlPoints[i + 3];

        if (i == 0) //only do this for the first end point. When i != 0, this coincides with the end point of the previous segment,
        {
            drawingPoints.Add(CalculateBezierPoint(0, p0, p1, p2, p3));
        }

        for (int j = 1; j <= SEGMENTS_PER_CURVE; j++)
        {
            float t = j / (float)SEGMENTS_PER_CURVE;
            drawingPoints.Add(CalculateBezierPoint(t, p0, p1, p2, p3));
        }
    }

    return drawingPoints;
}

/**
    This gets the drawing points of a bezier curve, using recursive division,
    which results in less points for the same accuracy as the above implementation.
*/
public List<Vector3> GetDrawingPoints2()
{
    List<Vector3> drawingPoints = new List<Vector3>();

    for (int curveIndex = 0; curveIndex < curveCount; curveIndex++)
    {
        List<Vector3> bezierCurveDrawingPoints = FindDrawingPoints(curveIndex);

        if (curveIndex != 0)
        {
            //remove the fist point, as it coincides with the last point of the previous Bezier curve.
            bezierCurveDrawingPoints.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        drawingPoints.AddRange(bezierCurveDrawingPoints);
    }

    return drawingPoints;
}

List<Vector3> FindDrawingPoints(int curveIndex)
{
    List<Vector3> pointList = new List<Vector3>();

    Vector3 left = CalculateBezierPoint(curveIndex, 0);
    Vector3 right = CalculateBezierPoint(curveIndex, 1);

    pointList.Add(left);
    pointList.Add(right);

    FindDrawingPoints(curveIndex, 0, 1, pointList, 1);

    return pointList;
}


/**
    @returns the number of points added.
*/
int FindDrawingPoints(int curveIndex, float t0, float t1,
    List<Vector3> pointList, int insertionIndex)
{
    Vector3 left = CalculateBezierPoint(curveIndex, t0);
    Vector3 right = CalculateBezierPoint(curveIndex, t1);

    if ((left - right).sqrMagnitude < MINIMUM_SQR_DISTANCE)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    float tMid = (t0 + t1) / 2;
    Vector3 mid = CalculateBezierPoint(curveIndex, tMid);

    Vector3 leftDirection = (left - mid).normalized;
    Vector3 rightDirection = (right - mid).normalized;

    if (Vector3.Dot(leftDirection, rightDirection) > DIVISION_THRESHOLD || Mathf.Abs(tMid - 0.5f) < 0.0001f)
    {
        int pointsAddedCount = 0;

        pointsAddedCount += FindDrawingPoints(curveIndex, t0, tMid, pointList, insertionIndex);
        pointList.Insert(insertionIndex + pointsAddedCount, mid);
        pointsAddedCount++;
        pointsAddedCount += FindDrawingPoints(curveIndex, tMid, t1, pointList, insertionIndex + pointsAddedCount);

        return pointsAddedCount;
    }

    return 0;
}



/**
    Caluclates a point on the Bezier curve represented with the four controlpoints given.
*/
private Vector3 CalculateBezierPoint(float t, Vector3 p0, Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2, Vector3 p3)
{
    float u = 1 - t;
    float tt = t * t;
    float uu = u * u;
    float uuu = uu * u;
    float ttt = tt * t;

    Vector3 p = uuu * p0; //first term

    p += 3 * uu * t * p1; //second term
    p += 3 * u * tt * p2; //third term
    p += ttt * p3; //fourth term

    return p;

}
}
```